# Neutral term for a person in the same organization

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nonsubjective

Is there a neutral term for a person who belongs to an organization to which I also belong, not implying a personal relationship?

Inside a business, one might use *colleague* or *peer*. Business to business, one might use *partner* (or *customer* or *vendor* or *supplier* to indicate the direction in which the business takes place). But in my case this is not a business relationship.

There are other special purpose terms. If it is a fraternal or church organization, one might use *brother* and *sister*, but in my case they won’t do.

*Co-participant* is neutral but seems to connote more a common activity than a common organization, and it is awkwardly long. *Confederate*, on the other hand, conveys a common organization but seems to have a negative connotation. *Fellow* might also do, but it seems to have an elitist or learned connotation.

I am not looking for a word that means *friend*, such as *companion* or *comrade*. That connotes a personal relationship which does not necessarily exist between members of an organization. *Comrade* also brings in the leftist political alignment.

Comment: How about combining words you've suggested into "fellow member"

Comment: "Co-conspirator"?

Comment: What is the nature of the organization? That might suggest some specific suggestions

Comment: It is a community organization for freethinkers. It organizes social activities which are freethinker friendly (e.g., no "God talk"), and charitable and promotional activities in its geographical area.

Comment: I should say that is the specific example I have in mind. However the only thing about its nature which enters into the question is negative: it's not a business, not a fraternal organization, and not a church. It might as well have been the Soroptimists or Habitat For Humanity.

Comment: I think "colleague" is actually the best choice out of everything suggested - though it's usually used in business and academia, it has a wider potential scope. I certainly think it would work fine for the organization you described.

Comment: @CarlSmith [Comments](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) are not for "secondary discussion or debating a controversial point; please use [chat] instead". Use the comment privilege only for discussion directly related to improving the original post.

Comment: I apologise. I just thought it was a confusing example that made it difficult to understand what type of organisation it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A synonym for [colleague](http://www.wordnik.com/words/colleague) is *[cooperator](http://www.wordnik.com/words/cooperator)*; or *[associate](http://www.wordnik.com/words/associate)*.

Comment: I am leaning toward *associate* based on the linked explanation under synonyms: "Associate is the most general word for persons who are connected in life, work, etc.; it is special only in suggesting an alliance of some permanence." This seems to capture the neutrality I am after without being specific to a particular type of organization.

Comment: Shall I add that text to my answer?

Answer (score 6):

You could say *fellow member*, although there are many instances where it would not be appropriate.

Comment: When would it be inappropriate?

Comment: Inappropriate in the sense that it might be used in some situations. I was thinking about the business-to-business case mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

As all we know is you are both members of some unspecified organisation, and we don't want to emphasise any particularly strong relationship between you both, the most neutral term I can think of is ***co-member***.

All this says is you are both members of something, but doesn't say much more.

Answer (score 1):

*Cohorts* can refer to groups of people; it can also refer to the members of such groups.

Answer (score 0):

"Fellow Traveler" can be fun, but can tweak anti-red noses.

Comment: Looking, though, for a word that denotes shared membership.